# Android: unable to change ImageView at run time

Tags: android

I am using ImageView in my example. **I set Images as background of imageview in xml**. Now I want to change this image background of Imageview at run time.

this is my java code.

```
 changeImage()

       {
       ImageView imgview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.headerhindi);
       }
```

I am calling this method from **onCreate()**. First time my method works fine. but when I redirect  again to my activity onCreate() using startActivity(myActivityIntent);  this method does not works properly means Images does not change according to this method. By default images which is set in xml is shown.

Please help me to find out the solution. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the call to `changeImage()` to `onResume()`.

I haven't tested it, but I have a feeling that what's happening is that when you call `startActivity()` to start the activity again, the activity was not destroyed yet so `onCreate()` is not called again as per the activity lifecycle:

[image]http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png. Just a hunch though.

Answer (score 1):

How to you redirect to your activity `onCreate` ?

If your activity was already running, it skips `onCreate` and goes directly to the `Started` state.
You probably want to move your `changeImage()` to the `onStart()` method which get called on creation and resuming.

[image]

You can see full explanations here: [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

*※ The main difference for you between `onStart()` and `onResume()` would be that `onStart()` is called before the activity becomes visible while `onResume()` is called after.*